# How do you search for a pattern and ignore case in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, sql-like

How would I make it so that this query is case insensitive so it finds instances of "Hop" and "hop" even when the search query is only "hop"

```
  const {
    rows,
  } = await db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM course WHERE header LIKE '%' || $1 || '%'",
    [req.body.searchbar]
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ILIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM course WHERE header ILIKE '%' || $1 || '%'
```

You can also express this with the `~~*` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM course WHERE header ~~* '%' || $1 || '%'
```